# Weird Pixellation, Almost Like Dealing With NGons But Different

Tags: objects, edit-mode, normals

I bought this element from CGTrader and imported as a obj file.  The pixellation doesn't seem to be from ngons.  The normals are facing outside.  My thoughts are that it has a ton of overlapping geometry.  Any thoughts on this?  Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y12UG.png)

Comment: Most likely duplicated geometry causing Z-fighting.

Comment: Yeah looks like it.  Thanks for the help @cegaton:)

Comment: when you download objects created by others you are downloading their bad modelling practices as well...